# find out the Multiple(Best) way to create Spring Web Application using angular js?

Tags: java, angularjs, spring-mvc

I'm trying to create an application using `Angular js` & `Spring Framework`.

Now I'm confused what will be the best way to create the spring app??

1. Using Regular Spring web Application with Jsp and integrate the Html code for angular in jsp and view Resolver?
2. Using any Generator (likely to have npm spring-angular generator).
3. Create new angular app and redirect the `/` to the angular application and change code in angular and server side will be only REST ?

Answer (score 0):

I think the third is the good way. Doing Spring REST service and a full HTML5/Javascript client with angularjs in second part. You can do that in one maven project using https://github.com/eirslett/frontend-maven-plugin